# How to create collectionview in tableView Cell in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, swift4

[image: image with comment[![image with out comment]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwfva.png)I have use one `tableView`. Inside `tableViewCell` i want to populate a `collectionView`. 
I have a static array

**Here is my code**

```
var menuImage = ["download.jpeg","download (1).jpeg","download (2).jpeg","download (3).jpeg","download (4).jpeg","download (3).jpeg","download (4).jpeg","download (3).jpeg","download (4).jpeg"]


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return menuImage.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:HomeTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell
        // cell.collectionView.reloadData()
        return cell
    }
```

**inside `tableViewCell` ->**

```
class HomeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
}
```

**and this is the `collectionView`**

```
extension HomeVC: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return menuImage.count
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
       return  1
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HomeCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeCollectionViewCell
        cell.imgvw.image = UIImage(named: menuImage[indexPath.row])
        cell.profileName.text = menus[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Collection view at row \(collectionView.tag) selected index path \(indexPath)")
    }
}
```

Still the static data is not showing. please help

Comment: how you set `collectionView`  `delegate and `dataSource`?

Comment: doesnot know where to set

Comment: @Kuldeep please help

Comment: @Kuldeep sir are you there?

Comment: yes, tell me.....

Comment: sir how to adjust textview height, means if the data is less then how to handle the textview height inside a collectionView?

Comment: you need to calculate textview content height and based on that you need to return collectioncell height

Comment: okay @Kuldeep sir

Comment: and another thing sir how to add a textview dynamically in collection View

Comment: you can add textview in CollectionViewCell xib file & you need to calculate text height in collectionView delegate. `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize { }`

Comment: i wrote this ..  if userOriginalDetails[indexPath.row].latest_comment.l_comment == "" {
          
            return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 490)
        } else {
            
            return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: nonExpandableHeight)
        }
        var nonExpandableHeight : CGFloat = 744

Comment: initially if the latestcomment is blank then the comment TextView will not appear. if user pos comment then the commentTextView will appear sir

Comment: I didn't understand, can you please attach screen.

Comment: okay sir i am attaching the screenshot

Comment: sir i have uploaded 2 screenshots, one is with comment, another is without comment. my problem is that if the cell loaded without comment in that case i am loading the cell height less,but when user post a comment i am unable to increase the height of collection View.

Comment: did you add Comment TextView inside CollectionViewCell? If YES then remove from collectionViewCell and Add below CollectionView from StoryBoard. So you can easily increase height of it.

Comment: Follow This Link to increase UITextView Height as per Text Content: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38714272/how-to-make-uitextview-height-dynamic-according-to-text-length

Comment: Okay sir following the link, yes i have add commentTextView inside collectionViewcell. Thank you sir

Comment: @Kuldeep sir how can i add Comment TextView outside the cell,(where the comments are showing). because it have to reusable one.

Comment: @Kuldeep how can i focus on a particular cell on a collectionView? sir i am using indexPathForPreferredFocusedView but still it is not coming.

Comment: @Kuldeep sir are you there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show all images below username than you need to change the `Layout`. it's not possible in that layout.

**so my suggestion is :** You display only user details in `HomeVC`, once any row is tapped, move to new screen and show user details along with all images like `instagram user profile`.

Edit of your Demo : https://www.dropbox.com/s/v05k2udqa3pu1dd/Demp1.zip?dl=0

Comment: then i have to write,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource in table view cell class?

Comment: yes, thats the good way to do this.

Comment: then what should in write in   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
    }

Comment: just return `menuImage.count` that you define in your `ViewController`

Comment: if i define menuImage in view controller and return the menuImage.count in numberOfRowsInSection then what should i write in numberOfItemsInSection as menuimage is define in HomeVC

Comment: where you define `var menuImage = ....` in HomeVC?

Comment: in HomeTableViewCell

Comment: i am getting a bit confused. can you help me out

Comment: HomeVC contains `tableView` and you want to load `collectionView` in that cells right?

Comment: yes exactly. collectionView  is in HomeTableViewCell

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169420/discussion-between-kuldeep-and-gorib-developer).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to Follow the steps mentioned in this Video [Collection View inside TableView cell](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ArzE1bZssQM)

Moreover you can refer this link also:
[Collectionview in tableview cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44104521/collectionview-in-tableview-cell)

Hope this helps.

### Issue in Image added

As stated by you , you have added the image directly to Xcode i.e. Drag and Drop,

So do cross check if the **Target Member** Ship is ticked or not.? If not the please tick that.

Also it is suggested to name the image properly like **image1,image2,image3,image4,etc** so that it gets detected without any issue.

[image]

### Edit Link to a demo Project added

You can find a demo of Collection View inside a tableView cell here: [Demo of imageCollectionView inside TableViewCell](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NQZe-VjfBxWlAvkYwVUDr6EKMpyYB0OH/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: what should i write numberOfRowsInSection?

Comment: I would suggest your array.coun

Comment: look sir there us only one array. menuImage. i have to count menuImage.count in both numberOfItemsInSection and numberOfRowsInSection?

Comment: Have you referred the video i posted the link of.? In that it is clearly explained how to return in numberofSections and also in the collection view. Please look into that once.

Comment: though already i have seen it.. but i am seeing it again sir

Comment: sir i have already seen this video, and follow the steps exactly but still the data is not showing

Comment: Have you tried printing the name of the image.? I think so the issue is in image, it is not getting returned.? Are the images in assets or directly Copied into the Xcode i.e. Drag and drop.?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169421/discussion-between-abhirajsinh-thakore-and-gorib-developer).

Comment: @GoribDeveloper Edited the answer with the demo link, lemme know if it works for you or not.?

Comment: okay sir .doing it